# Cannot make css rounded corners table in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

I read through the related posts but none of them can solve my case.

I have a table embedded in my WordPress site, I only take away the header menu and the footer, demo site can be visited from http://www.solepropr.net/demo/wordpress_table.html

If viewing the CSS setting for the first th border, the border-top-left-radius is 6px but the actual output is still a right angle. No matter how large of the radius size I set, there is no change to the corner.

Below is the output of the Computed style from Chrome Developer Tools

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 146, 215);
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: rgb(0, 146, 215);
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-width: 2px;
border-right-color: rgb(0, 146, 215);
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 2px;
border-top-color: rgb(0, 146, 215);
border-top-left-radius: 6px;  <<<<<<<<----------
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 2px;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(112, 112, 112);
direction: ltr;
display: table-cell;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add **CSS** property`border-collapse: separate` on e.g. the `.round-table` class

```
.round-table {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-collapse: separate; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks pbaldauf, it helps and solve the problem but I have no idea how the border-collapse: affect this, could briefly describe?

Comment: In the w3.org documentation (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-radius-tables) is written "CSS3 UAs should ignore border-radius properties applied to internal table elements when ‘border-collapse’ is ‘collapse’". That's unfortunately the only thing I can tell you.

Answer (score 1):

You have your borders and border-radius placed in the wrong spot.

For example, if you added this to your CSS you'll notice the effects you want:

```
#comp { 
border-radius: 10px;
border: 2px solid #0092d7;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can't set a border-radius property inside a th border.
The solution to this is to change the display to inline-block. However, it seems like that will add more problems.

I suggest removing the border from the th element and applying the border to the div outside the table. Add border-radius to the div and bamn, border radius shows up.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
remove border-collapse:colapse;
```

in your style sheet

and set

```
 <table class="round-table" width="100%" style="border:3px solid red;">
```